# How to Steady Aim on COD Warzone for PS4 while using the Bumper Jumper Tactical button layout?

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-warzone

I have set the Bumper Jumper Tactical layout that uses R3 for crouching. The problem is that R3 is also needed to Steady Aim when sniping with some particular scope, like the Variable Zoom Scope. So, when I try to Steady Aim, I get my character crouching instead.

Is there a way to fix this?

Ideally, I would like to have another button for the Steady Aim, keeping the Bumper Jumper Tactical layout mostly untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, even [reddit complains](https://www.reddit.com/r/CODWarzone/comments/fgup1y/is_there_a_way_to_customize_the_controller_button/) about a lack of rebinding. Unless you alter the layout you're using, you can't change the controls.

The best you can do is attempt to [remap your controller](https://www.howtogeek.com/245977/how-to-remap-buttons-on-your-playstation-4s-controller/), but beware that that changes your controller mapping for everything and is generally pretty unwieldy.